# The console of my application says "GET http://localhost:3000/test 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm a beginner in Node.js and I have big problems to make my React app work with it. I have created an API that works correctly since when I read "node server.js" I see the elements of my database. But when I want to make these requests via my React app, I always get an error in my localhost.

My application should be very simple, by simply pressing a button the result of my query should appear in my console

Moreover I use the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/test
```

and my terminal shows me this message:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /test from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

**API**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Elsalvador60?',
  database: 'reactapp'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to database: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to database with id ' + connection.threadId);
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM user', function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
  });
});

const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**REACT/NODE CODE**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class Button extends React.Component {


  handleClick = () => {
    axios.get('/test')
      .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Afficher les données</button>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "management-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {

      "target": "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
    },
  
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^8.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-backend": "node database.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "database.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: 1) You shouldn't use root database user for apps, or put passwords in plaintext, ever 2) What is `auth/google` supposed to be doing for your react package json if you have no Google related code 3) can you curl your api first before trying to use react?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run both your frontend and your backend on the same port, which is impossible.

Change one of the ports to something else (3001 for example) and it should be fine.